# Holomorphic function $f$ such that $f(1/n) = \cos(1/\sqrt{n}) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Does a holomorphic function $f$ exist such that
$$ f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \cos(1/\sqrt{n}), \quad n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1. $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is that $$f(z) = \cos(z^{1/2}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} z^k$$
is entire and fulfills the requirement,

and (by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)) there is no other solution being  analytic around $z=0$.